# Display flex heading being on top of three boxes

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In between 788px and 1024px viewport. I'm using display: flex (still a novice) is there a way without changing html and not using position:absolute to get the heading: "KONTAKT" on top of the three cat image boxes?

Maybe using a flex method or something else that hasnt popped into my head.

http://codepen.io/rKaiser/pen/zBXqmr

```
@media (max-width: 1024px)  {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left {width: 100%;}
  .contacts {width:100%;display:flex; flex-direction: row;}
  .box2 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .img { width: auto;}
  .content {  width:auto; text-align: center;}
  h2 {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

between `768px` and `1024px` , don't use flex because h2 will also be affected by that `display:flex; flex-direction:row` on `.content` . so instead , if you want your 3 `box2` to be on same row, use `float:left;width:33.33%;display:block` and so the h3 will be on top of them.

after that, below `768px` return to `display:flex` and you are set.

see snippet below or jsfiddle here > **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/4dgzmz0x/)**

let me know if it helps

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
h6 {
  font-size: 16px;
}
html, body {
  width:100%
}
.container {
  width:1170px;
  background: green;margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}
@media (max-width: 1169px)  {
  .container {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.left {
  width:70%;
  background: #99ccff;
}

.contacts {
  width:30%;
}

.box2 {
  width: 100%;
  background: #ff6699;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.img, .content {
  margin:10px;

}
.img {  width:40%;}
.content {  width:60%;}

.img img{
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px)  {
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .left {width: 100%;}
  .contacts {width:100%;}
  .box2 {
    float:left;width:33.33%;text-align:center;display:block;
  }
  .img { width: auto;}
  .content {  width:auto; text-align: center;}
  h2 {text-align:center;}
}

@media (max-width: 768px)  {
  .contacts {width:100%;display:flex; flex-direction: column;}
  .box2 {
    flex-direction: row;
    display:flex;
    width:100%;
  }
  .img { width: 50%; text-align: right}
  .content {  width:50%; text-align: left;}
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="left">
      Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature hfrom 45 BC, makging it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Lat
    </div>
    
    <div class="contacts">
      <h2>KONTAKT</h2>
      <div class="box2">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h6>Sven Svennsonn</h6>
          <h6>asdas@hot.ee21312</h6>
          <h6>asddasd as asd</h6>
          <h6>asdasd as asd</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box2">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h6>asdasd as daasd</h6>
          <h6>asdas dasda asd</h6>
          <h6>asdasd as asd</h6>
          <h6>asdasd as asd</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
      
        <div class="box2">
        <div class="img">
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/150/150" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <h6>Name Namesson3</h6>
          <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</h6>
          <h6>mail.mail@lorem.se</h6>
          <h6>+555 666 999</h6>
        </div>
      </div>
    
    
    </div>
  </div>
```